# How To Import Private Frameworks to Xcode 9.2 (iOS 11) , swift

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, private, xcode9.2

I want to test something for research purposes (not App Store!) in which I want to use the private frameworks in Xcode 9.2 (iOS 11). For that, I needed to import the private framework I want to use to my Xcode project.

But in Xcode 9.2 in folder structure private frameworks folder is not present.

Any ideas through which I can achieve that?

Comment: Which private framework you want to use? and how are you using that? please show code

Comment: If that framework is on Cocoapods, you can install it via pods, as you do for others.

Comment: @Nitish no it is not on Cocoapods, its a private framework of apple

Comment: @PPL I want to use BatteryCenter.framework. I have not written any code as of yet, as I am not sure how to import the framework first.

Answer (score 5):

A private framework is just a bundle like a public framework. You can load it explicitly with:

```
if let framework = Bundle(path: "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BatteryCenter.framework") {
    // Works only on real devices
    framework.load()
}
```

But you need declarations for the included classes. You might create them with [`class-dump`](https://github.com/nygard/class-dump) as Objective C headers, and import the over a bridging header into Swift.

You execute `class-dump` with `class-dump /.../PrivateFrameworks/XXX.framework/XXX`. You need the framework as binary not as `*.tbd` file. Example for `BatteryCenter.framework`:

> class-dump /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BatteryCenter.framework/BatteryCenter

This will print you class declarations for all classes contained in the framework.

Note, on a device or a simulator you should use

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BatteryCenter.framework
```

for loading the bundle.

Comment: how do we use class dump, I am not able to understand the same.

Comment: @nehaSingh: I've extended my post.

Comment: I used the following code to access teh bundle at the given path it it gives nil.           NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"];
        if (![bundle load]) {
            NSLog(@"Error"); // maybe throw an exception
        } else {
            _supporter = [NSClassFromString(@"BCBatteryDevice") valueForKey:@"sharedInstance"];
            _handler = [[BCBatteryDeviceHandler alloc] init];
        }

Comment: @nehaSingh: Your path doesn't point to a valid framework bundle. Please see my post above.The frameworks in the SDK directory doesn't contain a valid binary. The just contain .tbd files which can neither be loaded nor inspected by class dump.

Comment: BatterCenter.Framework does not exist at the given path : /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks ,

Comment: @nehaSingh: 1. Its name is `BatteryCenter.framework` (case and correct spelling are important), 2. This framework exists only on **real devices**.